# capture IP addresses only using R

Tags: regex, r, regex-negation

I have R objects that have domain names and IP addresses in them. For example.

```
11.22.44.55.test.url.com.localhost
```

I used regex in R to capture the IP addresses. My problem is that when there is no match the whole string gets matched or "outputed". This becomes a problem as I work on a very large dataset. I currently have the following using regex

```
sub("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+).*","\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4","11.22.44.55.test.url.com.localhost")
```

which gives me 11.22.44.55

```
11.22.44.55
```

but if I were to have to following

```
sub("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+).*","\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4","11.22.44.test.url.com.localhost")
```

Then it gives me

```
11.22.44.test.url.com.localhost
```

which is actually not correct. Wondering if there is any solution for this.

Comment: What behavior would you like in the second case ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pre-process with `grep` to get only the strings that are formatted they way you want them, then use `gsub` on those.

```
x <- c("11.22.44.55.test.url.com.localhost", "11.22.44.test.url.com.localhost")
gsub("((\\d+\\.){3}\\d+)(.*)", "\\1",  grep("(\\d+\\.){4}", x, value=TRUE))
#[1] "11.22.44.55"
```

Comment: +1 this gets around the default behaviour of returning unmatched strings intact.

Comment: Thanks @GSee this seems to be "the" solution to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your code is working. When `sub()` fails to match, it returns the original string. From the manual:

> For sub and gsub return a character vector of the same length and with the same attributes as x (after possible coercion to character). **Elements of character vectors x which are not substituted will be returned unchanged** (including any declared encoding). If useBytes = FALSE a non-ASCII substituted result will often be in UTF-8 with a marked encoding (e.g. if there is a UTF-8 input, and in a multibyte locale unless fixed = TRUE). Such strings can be re-encoded by enc2native.

Emphasis added

Comment: Did try that too gauden.`sub("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.*","\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4","11.22.44.test.url.com.localhost")` But that too yields. `11.22.44.test.url.com.localhost`. I am guessing this might have to do something with the way sub works in R?

Comment: The answer to this in something like the proposal by @GSee, though I would love to see a solution that does not need two passes on the data.

Comment: Unfortunate that there is a bit of convolution. Would love to see an solution that was straight forward in R.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern:

```
(?:\d{1,3}+\.){3}+\d{1,3}
```

I have tested it in Java:

```
static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d{1,3}+\\.){3}+\\d{1,3}");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s1 = "11.22.44.55.test.url.com.localhost";
    final String s2 = "11.24.55.test.url.com.localhost";
    System.out.println(getIps(s1));
    System.out.println(getIps(s2));
}

public static List<String> getIps(final String string) {
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        strings.add(m.group());
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Output:

```
[11.22.44.55]
[]
```

Comment: This does not translate easily to R (at least for me).  It looks like `perl=TRUE` will be needed, but that's about as far as I can get with it.

Comment: That's the same in Java - that group is non-capturing. The actual match is the whole pattern.

Comment: @bmorris591 Apologies I stand corrected. I had forgotten to capture the pattern repeat. You were right. Thanks again.

Comment: the R pattern syntax is different than Java

Comment: @Daghan what is different? This is _regex_ not R or Java. The Java is just there as a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `gsubfn` or `strapply` functions in the gsubfn package.  When you want to return the match rather than replace it, these functions work better than `sub`.